# Python - Apply function over pairwise elements of array without using loops

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Suppose I want to apply a function func over the pairwise elements of a numpy array A, and I want to produce an a new matrix M, where `M[i,j] = func(A[i],A[j])`. Is there someway to do this in Python without using loops?

Comment: We need more details about `func` to know whether it could be done without using loops.

Comment: For a start, learn the `broadcasting` rules, and how they work in contexts like addition, and other `ufunc`.  You can't actually avoid loops, you can only move them into fast compiled code.  That's where learning the `numpy` building blocks matters.

Comment: A crucial question - does `func(A[i],A[j])` only work with scalar values of `i` and `j`?

Comment: Are you sure you are stating the problem correctly? If `A` is a numpy array, then `A[i]` and `A[j]` are the `i`th and `j`th row vectors from `A`. Since you talk about operating on the elements of the array, possibly you mean `M[i, j] = func(A[i, j])`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, simply something like this (assuming your `func` is a nice numpy friendly function):

```
A = np.arange(5)

def f(x,y):
    return x+2*y

X,Y = np.meshgrid(A,A)

M = f(X,Y)
```

If not numpy friendly you may want to look at `np.vectorize`.

Comment: With a function like `x+2*y`, you don't need meshgrid.  Just take advantage of broadcasting: `x[:,None]+2*y`

Comment: True but meshgrid is general and a nobrainer, using broadcasting can quickly become a headache (where to and not to put the `None` axis) in more complex cases like `f(x,y) = x+2*y+x@y[::-1]`. But that's a fair price to pay if you want optimized code... :)